# Define inline no-op function such that arguments don't get evaluated

Tags: c++, macros, namespaces

In C++ with macros I can create a macro like:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#define Debug(__str__) std::cerr << "Debug: " << (__str__) << std::endl;
#else
#define Debug(__str__) (void)0
#endif
```

In deployment code (with `NDEBUG` set), in the call

```
Debug(generate_state_description());
```

The function `generate_state_description()` would never be called, because the call gets removed by the preprocessor.

Is there a way to get a similar effect using inline functions (which can be in a namespace) or similar instead of macros?

Comment: What's the matter with macros anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use it in the same way with the same efficency.  This is because using it in the same way would result in your function always being called, but then just not passing it to cout.

To avoid doing that you'll have to pass around the function pointer (or std::function / lambda expression) for the same efficiency; but if you're willing to do that you can make a template function that looks something like

```
template<typename T>
log(T x) {
  #ifndef NDEUBG
    cout << x << endl;
  #endif
}
```

and then specialise for functions.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK code itself don't know anything about defines and preprocessor stuff. You need check defines in preprocessor phase.

So you can do thingks like that. It's impossible to get rid of `#ifdefs`

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
Debug(const std::string& str) {std::cerr << "Debug: " << str << std::endl;}
#else
Debug(const std::string&) {}
#endif
```